# return value from recursive method in java when returning math expresion

Tags: java, recursion, methods, return, expression

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println(f(3));
    
}//end main

public static int f(int i) {
    if(i<=1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return(2+f(i-1));
    }
}
```

This function call returns 5 when I put 3 as an argument but I can't figure out why

Comment: It's a recursive function. `f(3)` returns a value containing `f(2)` which returns a value containing `f(1)`.

Comment: So basically it returns `(2 + (2 + (1)))` (paratheses depicting calls to `f()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet that might help explain the order of operations. It's written in JavaScript, but the recursion is the same.

Your call to `f(3)` has to compute `f(2)` before it can return a value.

In turn, `f(2)` has to compute `f(1)` before it can return  a value.

`f(1)` is the base case and is specified to be equal to `1`.

Once `f(2)` knows that `f(1) = 1`, it can finish its own calculation and return `(2 + 1) = 3`.

Once `f(3)` knows that `f(2) = 3`, it can finish its own calculation and return `(2 + 3) = 5` which is your result.

```js
function f(i) {
  console.log(`f(${i}) called.`);
  
  if (i <= 1) {
    console.log(`f(${i}) returned 1.`);
    return 1;
  }
  
  console.log(`Getting value of f(${i - 1}) because i = ${i} which is > 1.`);
  let r = f(i - 1);
  
  console.log(`f(${i}) used f(${i - 1}) = ${r} to calculate (2 + ${r}).`);
  r = (2 + r);
  
  console.log(`f(${i}) returned ${r}.`);
  return r;
}

console.log(`Result: ${f(3)}.`);
```

Comment: Thank for all the example explanations It really helped a lot i

Answer (score 0):

You put 3 and it subtracts 1 which equals 2 and then does the recursion which is 2 minus 1 that is 1.  Finally it adds 2 + 2 + 1 which is equal to 5.

Comment: thank you so much its really helpful I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation proceeds as follows:

`f(3)`
`2 + f(2)`
`2 + (2 + f(1))`
`2 + (2 + 1)`
`2 + 3`
`5`

Comment: Thank you for that best way to explain